# Calling telnet from an ssh command

Tags: ssh, telnet

I am trying to figure out a problem, which I have to do in a certain way, unfortunately.

When I ssh into a remote host and log in (this will require a login), it is successful. If I then telnet to another host, telnet works fine.

However, I need to find a way to call telnet from the ssh command when I issue this command:

```
ssh FIRSTHOST 'telnet SECONDHOST'
```

(Yes, I am supposed to make this command work.)

When I try to login to the second host (after logging into the first), the input is simply echoed to the screen, and not sent to the second host.

-- Added example from comments -----------
`ssh 172.24.128.1 <RETURN>` followed by `telnet 172.20.1.1` WORKS but the command `ssh 172.24.128.1 'telnet 172.20.1.1'` will NOT connect properly to the telnet session; any keystokes are echoed without being processed.

An example below

```
[hmuser@localhost ~]$ ssh 172.24.128.1 'telnet 172.20.1.1'   
hmuser@172.24.128.1's password:   
Trying 172.20.1.1... 
Connected to 172.20.1.1.   
Escape character is '^]'.   
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service login: sdf sdf
```

---

I have tried several options, including setting remote ports.

I can't seem to find anything on the web for this. Duplicating this would be good and finding a solution to this would be great.

Comment: `$ ssh 127.0.0.1 'echo a b'` <-- displays  `a b`    and `$ ssh 127.0.0.1 'ls a'`  displays- the file `a` if it exists.   So i'd have thought what you wrote would work. Can you copy/paste from the command line into your post

Comment: ssh  172.24.128.1
<RETURN> followed by telnet 172.20.1.1 WORKS but the command ssh  172.24.128.1 'telnet 172.20.1.1' will NOT connect proplery to the telnet session; any keystokes are echoed without being processed. An example below 
[hmuser@localhost ~]$ ssh  172.24.128.1 'telnet 172.20.1.1'
hmuser@172.24.128.1's password: 
Trying 172.20.1.1...
Connected to 172.20.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service 

login: dcp
dcp                                     And I can't put carraige returns in this comment, so I hope it's readable

Comment: When you SSH, do you get `C:\blah>`  (e.g. you're running a windows native ssh server like bitvise)  or do you get `$`(e.g. you're running cygwin ssh server) ?    I'm not sure if it's an issue with the windows telnet client, maybe it's not, (since you say it works when done as a separate command) , though the windows telnet client is terrible.   I don't have an answer at the moment but as an alternative you could try the cygwin ssh server on the windows machine, and use the nc command instead of telnet. You could try putty on the remote machine..

Comment: 'I get a login screen. In the cut and paste  below, I have shown what happens when I try to login - it just preseats the input user name, without actually doing anyting (I am waiting for the "password" prompt 'code' [hmuser@localhost ~]$ ssh  172.24.128.1 "telnet 172.20.1.1"
hmuser@172.24.128.1's password: 
Trying 172.20.1.1...
Connected to 172.20.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service 

login: sdf
sdf
'

Comment: where the "sdf sdf" is really telnet echoing the inpt user name, rahter than offering me the password.

Comment: Can you make a screenshot paste it on imgur.com and edit your post and give a link. And what SSH server are you using? And what SSH client are you using? Can you link to both

Comment: WAG: Does your telnet client need a TTY?  (in which case `ssh -t` ).

Comment: yes it does! -t solves it! Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing TTY should solve this issue. Sorry for coming too late.

```
ssh -t FIRSTHOST 'telnet SECONDHOST'
```

Please mark it as a solution to remove this question from "unanswered".